# Java Spring Framework return json with mysql

Tags: java, mysql, json, spring-mvc

I need an example of spring with MYSQL return JSON output.

- Get a list of MYSQL database(table like users)
- Show these records on another page with JSON format.

Comment: To get little bit forward in your project, i'd suggest you to read (and try) this through: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this would help you. Go through this example.
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/

Comment: I have used already these example. 

See below code

Shop shop = new Shop();
shop.setName(name);
shop.setStaffName(new String[]{"mkyong1", "mkyong2"});

i need these variables(shop.setName(name)) using mysql not a statics

Comment: Then along with the Spring, you need to use Hibernate to retrieve the data. Instead of returning hard coded values, you can read the data from db using session object. You can get some idea if you refer this http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-save-get-blob-object-spring-3-mvc-hibernate/